# Selecting Records from a duplicate column whose value in another column is less than

Tags: oracle

Below is an example of my table:

```
  Column A         Column B       Column C
    Tom              Blue           10
    Tom              Orange         12
    Alex             Blue           30
    Alex             Orange         29
    Lisa             Orange         15
    Lisa             Blue           14
```

Output:

```
Column A      Blue        Orange
 Tom           10           12
 Lisa          14           15
```

The output above returns when there are two duplicate values in Column A, Column B Blue value in Column C is less than Column B Orange value in Column C.

So far I have... `select Column A, Column B as "Blue", Column B as "Orange" from table where Blue < Orange;`. Obviously where Blue < Orange doesn't work but that's the logic.

I think I need to write a subquery but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Would you provide code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Create Table

> ```
> create table t1(
> col1    varchar2(20), 
> col2    varchar2(20), 
> col3    number
> );
> ```

#### Sample Data

> ```
> insert into t1 
> select 'Tom','Blue','10' from dual
> union all
> select 'Tom','Orange', '12' from dual
> union all
> select 'Alex','Blue','30' from dual
> union all
> select 'Alex','Orange', '29' from dual
> union all
> select'Lisa','Orange','15' from dual
> union all    
> select 'Lisa','Blue','14' from dual;
> ```

#### Select Query

> ```
> select * from
>   (
>       select *
>       from t1
>   )
>   pivot
>   (
>     MIN(col3) for col2 in ('Blue' as blue,'Orange' as orange)
>   ) where blue<orange;
> ```

#### Output

> ```
> COL1  BLUE    ORANGE
> Tom   10      12
> Lisa  14      15
> ```

[dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1495027db5878c4dbf155d2b77cb936d)